# How to embed .NET Framework 4.0 into c# project

Tags: c#

I make a c# application project. this project run on my computer good, but in other computer says you must first install .NET Framework 4.0 to run this application.
How to embed .net framework 4.0 into c# project.
Thanks

Comment: You can *bundle* the .NET installer (web or full) with your application as a dependency that is installed when your application is installed. This must be installed before the .NET code is run of course: something like [DotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) (or a setup project or WiX or..) can be used to prepare the installer/dependency bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed the framework into your application sine it needs to be installed on the client machine (not just xcopy'd like your app).

You'll need to create an installer which will take care of detecting and installing the required framework version before installing your application.

Comment: It's not directly applicable just now, but it seems that future versions of .Net will allow "native" compilation of C# down to C++, and will NOT require the .NET framework to be installed on the user's machine - wow! See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-net-native-preview.aspx

Comment: @KenD this is for Store Apps. Desktop Apps will still be uncompilable to completely static code because of the features they provide.

Comment: @nvoigt: Ah that's a pity :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project) which shows how to create a setup project.

Once everything is set up, go to Project > [project name] Properties, click the Prerequisites... button and check .Net Framework 4. By default, the setup will download the Framework from Microsoft, so it will need an internet connection.

Comment: Setup Projects no longer exist with VS2012 and up.

Comment: @Macro Setup Projects have been [re-added to VS2013 as an extension](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project) and have been promised to be fully integrated again in the next version.

Comment: *Prerequisites* can also be found under Project > [project name] Properties > Publish > Install Mode and Settings